# Error parsing XML:unbound prefix

Tags: android, xml, animation

I am getting an error on this page meanwhile running the code, please help me if any error is seen here..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>

    <rotate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="360" />

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="10"
        android:toXDelta="" />

    <scale android:fromXScale="" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.5" />

</set>
```

Comment: [2012-08-14 16:01:52 - Animate] Error in an XML file: aborting build. there is a red cross near rotate. there is no error in log cat.

Comment: Hi, please write the error received as a part of your question.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning/refreshing the project?

Comment: Error parsing XML:unbound prefix

Comment: Why this line android:fromXScale="" XScale value is empty?

Comment: even if i keep only rotate code init. Itz showing error. I tried creating new XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <!-- XMLNS IMPORTANT-->

    <rotate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="360" />

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="10"
        android:toXDelta="" />

    <scale android:fromXScale="" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.5" />
```

Comment: thanks dude. It worked :) Was the error due to empty set feild..?

Comment: @NewbieRock, the first element of the xml need to import the namespace, it doesn't matter if it's s `set` element or another one.